# Converting epoch time to human-readable date in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a Unix epoch time. How can I convert it to a human-readable date string? I have examined clj-time (https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) but it appears to only go from readable-to-epoch. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use native calls:

```
(str (java.util.Date. (System/currentTimeMillis)))
;; => "Mon Feb 29 21:59:51 MSK 2016"
```

Comment: Or, perhaps preferably nowadays, `(java.time.Instant/ofEpochMilli (Long/parseLong "1456774240403"))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can coerce it to a date time and then use the formatters (built-in or build your own).

```
(require '[clj-time.format :as f])
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as c])

(f/unparse  (f/formatters :date-time) (c/from-long 1000000000000))
```

Note that `c/from-long` takes milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

For a code working in both clj and cljs you could use [tick](https://juxt.github.io/tick/)

```
(require '[tick.core :as tick])
(tick/inst (tick/instant (inst-ms #inst "2023-10-24T11:00:15.251-00:00")))

;; => #inst "2023-10-24T11:00:15.251-00:00"
```